# SharePoint: How to call function from another webparts?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, callback

I'm new to SharePoint. I'm developing some Client-side Webparts using Javascript/Typescript. I've already done the developments of Webparts separately. But I still cannot connect them. I still do not know how to call/trigger functions which are defined inside another webparts. But those webparts need to be connected through a chain of processes.

May I know how that can be achieved in SharePoint ecosystem please?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways coming to my mind. The first SPFX-way is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/dynamic-data

The second way which worked for me is that you will use the global window object to "transfer" data. For example you could have a sender webpart (using react here and just posting the components itself here because the webpart ts file is more or less unchanged).

```
const WebpartSender:React.FC<{ context: WebPartContext; }> = ({ context }) => {

  const sendValues = () => {
    console.log("sending values");
    (window as any)["receiveValues"]({
      value: "some data here"
    })
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={sendValues}>Send</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and a receiver webpart.

```
const WebpartReceiver:React.FC<{ context: WebPartContext; }> = ({ context }) => {

  const [ value, setValue ] = React.useState<string>("");

  const receiveValues = (valueObject: { value: string }) => {
    console.log("received value");
    setValue(valueObject.value);
  };

  (window as any)["receiveValues"] = receiveValues;

  return (
    <div>
      Value: {value}
    </div>
  );
};
```

So in the receiving webpart you define a function that sets the state and "receives" the values. This function is then added as property to the window object.

In the sending webpart this property on the window object is called whenever the values change. For example on a button click. In your case it would be when the api comes back with data.

You should include checks if the property is on the window object, use a unique name (to prevent that your custom function is overridden by something from SharePoint) and so on. This is probably not the "best" way, because all your webparts need to know the property name, but its working.

For the plain javascript/typescript version your receiver webpart could have something like this in the onInit method:

```
(window as any)["receiveValues2"] = ((that) => {
  return (valueObject: { value: string }) => {
    that._myData = valueObject.value;
    that.render();
  };
})(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have below options in SPFx for your requirements:

1. [SPFx library component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/library-component-overview): Library components provide you an alternative option to create shared code, which can be then used and referenced cross all the components in the tenant.
2. [SPFx dynamic data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/dynamic-data): You can connect two or more SharePoint Framework components together and exchange data between them using dynamic data.